# Splash Screen and login screen in React native with stack navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Currently i'm new to react native i saw the official site they have released 0.47. I looking for the splash screen and login screen in react native.  i find examples for do the splash screen in android, but i don't want to touch the mainactivity.java in android.I have saw examples using navigator which is deprecated and separated in different package. I planning to do with stack navigator. Is there any examples using stack navigator with splash screen and login screen?

Comment: You can use this module for creating forms, this will get you going with a login form in no time. https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples on how to make login screen in react native. But you can also try to make your own, first try to clear react native concepts. 
About stack navigator, first read about it do some research how to use it. Then you can use async storage to save user state. Based on user state you can navigate to either login screen or splash screen .
Below is a link to understand stack navigator. 
[stack navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack)

Comment: I myself have implemented it in one of my projects.

Comment: can i get some use full references link ?? because i new to this mobile technology

Comment: If you want to create login screen using library , here is one https://github.com/dwicao/react-native-login-screen . If you understand basic stack navigator, then I can help you implementing it

Comment: thanks Paras :-) let me get back to you, when i struggle some where in stack navigator

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to code it for you, but the general guidelines are:

First you need to create a component to hold your splashScreen. This should be a simple component, just an image and maybe an ActivityIndicator.

The utility of the Splash screen is to load the assets that the app requires to function properly.

- If this is your case then you should define an Async componentDidMount() and there load every asset your app may need using *await* for every async load you have. Once everything is loaded, redirect your user to the LoginComponetn using the navigator you like the most.
- If you just want to have a fancy splash screen for the mere purpose of having one, then just set up a 2 seconds timer on the componentDidMount() and then redirect your user to the Login Screen.

Note: remember to disable the android back button in the login screen to prevent your users from going back to the login screen.

Note2: I don't know which navigator are you usig but you should check ReactNavigation and React Native Router Flux. I personally like the second option because is better maintained and it's an API with improvements over the first one.

Good luck! Comment for doubts!